# What to do with the question "Storing Images in DB - Yea or Nay?"

Tags: discussion, status-completed, specific-question

[Storing Images in DB - Yea or Nay?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748/storing-images-in-db-yea-or-nay) is the 48<sup>th</sup> highest-voted question listed on Stack Overflow.

It's a very broad question, without a platform or language specified, and has accumulated 58 answers during the three-and-a-half years since it was posted. It is currently open and unlocked.

I don't think this question is appropriate for Stack Overflow by modern standards; the lack of details makes it very difficult to compare the merits of different answers. On the other hand, it has been popular (37k views and a score of 415) and does contain some useful information.

What should be done with it?

Comment: Who says "Yea or Nay"? It's supposed to be Yay or Nay. o.o

Comment: @animuson: [Yea](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/yea) or [nay.](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nay) Your version is [yay](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/yay) or [boo](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/boo)

Answer (score 7):

Historical lock. The question's too far gone to be fixed, but has some value as it is. We don't want this representing the site as a top question, but it doesn't need to be deleted.

Comment: +1, I use that for evidence and contains very useful information.